# Is it possible to create multiple openstack networks using same heat resource

Tags: openstack

Is it possible to create multiple networks using same resource and iterate through a list of names, instead of creating a long list of resources?
Like the example below:

```
parameters:
  netName:
    type: comma_delimited_list
    label: netName
    default: "calea,diam,ss7,proxy"
    description: Network name
resources:
  repeat:
    template:
      networks:
        type: OS::Neutron::Net
          properties:
            name:
              list_join: ['_', [ 'int', <%name%>, 'net']]
    for_each:
      <%name%>: { get_param: netName }
```